# Overlay Image in Android

Tags: android, imageview

How to overlay two images like the one in iphone notification icon or new launcher pro notification? I want to add new image on top right of an imageview to show notification

Here is the example of launcher pro notification and tweetcaster checked button (with facebook icon on topright)

http://londatiga.net/images/overlayimg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use Framelayout.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

thanks